# jquery ajax function return html code

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I using jquery library with CodeIginter, but the returned data is html code  of the view.

It should return the output of method in controller. Here is my ajax code:

```
$("#btn-delete").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "edit_questions/delete_question",
    data: {
      'q_id': 12
    },
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

and here is my controller

```
<?PHP 
 class edit_questions extends CI_controller{
    var $feed=array();
    public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model("Admin_db_model");
    $this->feed['status']=-1;
    $this->feed['msg']='';
   }
public function index(){



    $this->load->view("edit_questions_view",$this->feed);
}

public function show_questions(){

    $this->feed['q_list']=$this->Admin_db_model->get_question_titles($this-
    >uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->view('edit_questions_view',$this->feed);

}


public function delete_question(){


    echo"تم الحذف ".$this->input->post('q_id')  ;
    }   


}
```

And this is a screenshot for what i get in alert function 
[image]

Comment: it would be good to also include the code of the actual script. The controller of 'edit_question/delete_question'

Comment: Where's your controller method?

Comment: my controller method just have echo "text" i am trying to be sure it calls correctly first

Comment: @Jeff i added the controller

Comment: What else is in the html (that's not shown in the question) ?   eg it could be a 404 or a 500 generic page being sent by your server.

Comment: @freedomn-m it print the returned data it shows  all the current view html code  it looks like it reload the view page

Answer (score 2):

Try this **dataType: "html"** instead of dataType: "text"

Comment: Ok. Put exit or die() at the end of action. Use as well echo "تم الحذف ".$this->input->post('q_id') ;

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have already tried, some good first steps to debug this are:

- Ensure that the function delete_question() is run by putting
  something like `die("X marks the spot")` into it's body, and then
  searching for it in the alert message.
- Check the Developer Tools of you browser (right click, inspect
  element) and go to the Network tab, refresh that page, your AJAX
  request should appear there. Are there errors?

It seems like your web-server is responding with HTML, where you only expect a single string. A standard web server would not do this, unless the page returns with an Error, i.e 404 Errors do come with an HTML template depending on your configuration. Since the text is cut off in your alert box I cannot confirm that this is not the case.

If it is *not* a generic error, somewhere in your stack you must be outputting HTML outside of `<?php ?>` tags or inside `echo` statements.

If you are looking to further debug this, I recommend trying to initialize an Output Buffer, on the first line of the first PHP script in your stack. [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), later $html = [ob_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php), and [ob_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php).

This will catch ALL attempts of PHP to output HTML to the client, and temporarily suspends them in the buffer. With this, it may be easier for you to find where your script outputs content where it should not. I find it good practice to use output buffers to gain more control over what data the client receives

Since you are using a PHP framework, some of the URL mappings may be out of your control, therefore, you may use `var_dump(debug_backtrace())` to find out where your script starts.